# Authoring MP3 DVDs with Loop Playback option

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning, authoring

Okay, so this is what I want to do...

I have a mp3 file of size 40MB. I want to burn it onto a DVD (4.5 GB size) with "loop playback" functionality. That is, I want this 40MB mp3 file to repeat itself once it completes playing until I eject the DVD from my DVD Player.

I know you would say, "why not use the Repeat button on the DVD Player?". I am writing this DVD for one of my blind friend and hence, I would really appreciate it if this MP3 can play over and over as soon as I insert the DVD without having to press any 'Repeat' key in the DVD Player's remote control.

One way I can think of is.. copy and merge this 40MB size MP3 till it grows to a 4.5 GB size MP3 and then burn it in the DVD. But the again, it will not loop playback. I mean it will not start over once after playing the 4.5GB sized MP3.

I currently own Nero 7 and I do not seem to have any options to do this loop playback. Are there any other tools that can help me do this? I would not mind buying it no matter how much ever it costs. Thanks!

PS: I tried ConvertXToDVD software. Unfortunately, it only burns video files on to a DVD with a loop playback option. It does not help in burning MP3 files onto the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Does ConvertXToDVD, or any of you existing software allow you to create slide shows from pictures and videos?  You could use a single image, or multiple, whatever suits you to make a slideshow with the MP3 as the soundtrack.  I use uLead DVD MovieFactory because it came with my burner, and has the capability to do this, although it's a pretty basic feature, so most  DVD authoring programs should be able to accomplish this.  Alternatively, you could use some video editing software (anything you have should work) to switch out the original soundtrack in some random video, and burn that to the disk in loop mode.